# How to convert code in Mathematica to Python?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, graph, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I've the following Mathematica code to scale the edge length of a graph to be equal to edge weights.
([ref](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight))

```
edges = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 7, 6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8, 2 <-> 9};

vd = {{75., 25., 0}, {115., 45., 0}, {10., 5., 0}, {45., 0, 0}, 
  {90., 60., 0}, {45., 55., 0}, {0, 25., 0}, {10., 50., 0}, {115.,  25.,0}};

vl = Range[Length@vd];

vcoords = MapIndexed[#2[[1]] -> # &, vd];
ew = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 49.6, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 74.4, 
 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 49.6, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 74.4, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6 -> 49.6, 
 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4 -> 37.2, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 24.8, 
 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7 -> 62, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8 -> 37.2, 
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 24.8}

g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", Center]}, 
  VertexSize -> .3, VertexStyle -> Red]
vars3d = Array[Through[{x, y, z}@#] &, Length @ vd];

λ = 1/100.;

obj3d = Total[(Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] - # /. ew)^2 & /@ 
  EdgeList[g3d]] +  λ Total[Norm /@ (vars3d - vd)];

lbnd = 0;
ubnd = 500;

solution3d = Last@Minimize[{obj3d, And @@ Thread[lbnd <= Join @@ vars3d <= ubnd]}, 
    Join @@ vars3d];

edgeLengths3d = # -> Norm[vars3d[[First@#]] - vars3d[[Last@#]]] /. 
     solution3d & /@ EdgeList[g3d];

Grid[Prepend[{#, # /. ew, # /. edgeLengths3d} & /@ 
   EdgeList[g3d], {"edge", "EdgeWeight", "Edge Length"}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

I am trying to rewrite the same code in Python. The inputs have been converted to
python data types lists and dict.

```
edges = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,5), (2,6), (5,6), (3,4), (3,7), (6,7), (7,8), (2,9)];
vl = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ew = {(1, 2) : 49.6, (1,3): 74.4, (1, 4) : 49.6, (2,5): 37.2, (2, 6) : 74.4, (5, 6): 49.6, 
     (3, 4) : 37.2, (3, 7):24.8, (6, 7) : 62, (7, 8) : 37.2, (2, 9) : 24.8}
vd = {1:[75., 25., 0], 2:[115., 45., 0], 3:[10., 5., 0], 4:[45., 0, 0], 
      5:[90., 60., 0], 6:[45., 55., 0], 7:[0, 25., 0], 8:[10., 50., 0], 9:[115.,  25.,0]};
```

I'm not sure how the optimizations commands must be converted in Python.
Suggestions on how to write the lines `obj3d` and `solution3d` in Python will be of great help.

Comment: Can you explain each step of the Mathematica code or can you describe your desired output? I'm sure this will help Pythonists understand your problem and thereby help you solve it. ;)

Comment: @AnnieFromTaiwan Could you please have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight/220576#220576) post?

Comment: @Natasha can you take a look at these post they might be helpful: [converting to middle languange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85445/convert-mathematica-math-expression-form-to-python-math-expression) and [translation library](https://github.com/gwiederhecker/ToPython)

Comment: @Natasha Please check out my answer below. Is this a good enough answer for the bounty? Well that must be your call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Converting Mathematica to Python

This has only been done to some extent using various languages and tools, and I don't know of a complete solution to this as of yet.

I've researched it a bit and viable routes could be either:

`Mathematica -> SymPy / ANTLR -> Python`
or
`Mathematica -> C / Fortran -> Callable from Python`

The Mathematica way of doing things are (naturally) more functional than object oriented in nature, so translating directly to Python would probably be possible, but would result in some fairly hairy looking Python code.

If you do want to continue down the `Mathematica -> Python`route, there is a really smart guy (senior scientist at Quantum Information and Foundations Group CSIC), named Juan José García Ripoll that has started a tool for converting Mathematica Notebooks to Python directly.

It uses a pretty straight forward parser based method, that basically crawls through the Mathematica expression, translates operators into Python equivalents and creates a valid Python expression out of it.
It works for the most simple operations for the time being, but it would be a nice starting point if you don't want to start from scratch.

It is already capable of translating Mathematica expressions like:

[image]

Into Python code, so it's not *that* basic. Not a bad starting point.

You can download a Mathematica Notebook file that includes code and example
[here](https://juanjose.garciaripoll.com/blog/converting-mathematica-to-python/Export%20to%20Python.nb)

The blog post that explains this tool is [here](https://juanjose.garciaripoll.com/blog/converting-mathematica-to-python/)

The [Mathics](https://mathics.org) project also contains some interesting code in the same domain. You might want to check out the related [source files](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/search?l=mathematica).

I know this doesn't fully answer your question, but it does provide pointers to a possible solution for making it work, albeit this requires some work.

---

Answer (score 6):

> How to convert code in Mathematica to Python?

If the code is small (a few hundred lines), you'll better do the conversion by hand (or subcontract it).

#### You'll need to read the documentation of [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) and of [Python](https://python.org/).

If the code is big (many dozen of thousands lines), you could consider coding a [source to source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) translator. For that, read the [*Dragon* book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) then choose a high-level programming language (such as [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) or [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/)) to code such a translator (using parser generator tools like [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Efpottier/menhir/), [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) and approaches inspired by [Iburg](https://drhanson.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/documents/iburg.pdf) etc...). Budget half a year of full time work.